# How can I remove vertical space between tabular and longtable with \offinterlineskip

Tags: tables, longtable

Consider this MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}
\centering  

\bgroup
\offinterlineskip
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
        \hline
        foo & bar \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}

    \begin{tabular}{cc}
        \hline
        foo & bar \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\par
\egroup

\bigskip

\bgroup
\offinterlineskip
\begin{tabular}{cc}
    \hline
    foo & bar \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}

\begin{longtable}{cc}
    \hline
    foo & bar \\
    \hline
\end{longtable}
\par
\egroup


\end{document}
```

[image]

Why space between tabular and longtable cannot be removed with `\offinterlineskip` such as the case of the two simple tabular

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\offinterlineskip` disables baseline-to-baseline spacing calculations but does not disable explicit space added by display environments.

`longtable` adds `\LTpre` space before the table so:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}
\centering  

\bgroup
\offinterlineskip
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
        \hline
        foo & bar \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}

    \begin{tabular}{cc}
        \hline
        foo & bar \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\par
\egroup

\bigskip

\bgroup
\offinterlineskip
\setlength\LTpre{0pt}
\setlength\LTpost{0pt}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
    \hline
    foo & bar \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}

\begin{longtable}{cc}
    \hline
    foo & bar \\
    \hline
\end{longtable}
\par
\egroup


\end{document}
```