# What is the function of \offinterlineskip

Tags: spacing, line-spacing

Please excuse me if this is silly question...

Can any one explain the function of `\offinterlineskip`? And where should be applicable?

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/374316/how-can-i-remove-vertical-space-between-tabular-and-longtable-with-offinterline

Comment: @CampanIgnis no, I don't think it does.

Comment: @CampanIgnis yes I know, but it's my answer that you are referring to, and it doesn't explain what offinterlineskip is for, just that it was not doing what the questioner expected in the case of longtable.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I did not noticed that the other answer was yours, too. I guess you are right after all. Thank you for your work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\offinterlineskip` is a macro defined as

```
\def\offinterlineskip{%
  \baselineskip=-1000pt
  \lineskip=0pt
  \lineskiplimit=\maxdimen
}
```

so within its scope TeX makes no attempt to make even line spacing and just stacks things vertically.

Compare the normal setting on the right where a line of . gets the same space as a line of A, with the setting with `\offinterlineskip`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\parbox[t]{3cm}{\offinterlineskip
A A A A A A A A A A A A 
A A A A A A A A A A A A 
A A A A A A A A A A A A 
x x x x x x x x x x x x 
x x x x x x x x x x x x 
x x x x x x x x x x x x 
. . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . .
}
\parbox[t]{3cm}{
A A A A A A A A A A A A 
A A A A A A A A A A A A 
A A A A A A A A A A A A 
x x x x x x x x x x x x 
x x x x x x x x x x x x 
x x x x x x x x x x x x 
. . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . .
}

\end{document}
```

Obviously this looks fairly horrible if used for paragraphs of text as here but it can be useful in special situations where you have constructed boxes with specific contents that want to be stacked exactly without TeX inserting any additional inter-line space.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation....

Comment: After use of `\offinterlineskip`, how to restore the original vertical confugeration? It seems there is not a macro named `oninterlineskip`.

Comment: @lyl it's just three `\setlength` commands. Like any other settings, normally you do them in a group so they revert at the end.